# Show lists between subsites in the same collection (or how to web part)?

Tags: list, 2016, sync

The issue:

E.g. Subsite A has List A; Subsite B has List B

I want to show a list on different Subsites in the same collection.
Technically establish a CRUD like connection/two-directional sync, so I can Create, Read, Update and Delete on either List (or webpart thereof) and have it update the other list (or a central one).

I tried webparts, but 'Apps' of other subsites don't show up.

We have on-premise Sharepoint 2016.

Sorry if my definitions are not exactly correct, but I'm translating from German where there are Websites and Websitesites - a terminology mess.

I am fairly new to Sharepoint - but I'm not bad at IT stuff. So if you can at least point me in the direction of what to search for, because I'm close to pulling my hair out, because I just don't know how to find the knowledge I need.

Good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this to be the best *(kind of)* OOTB (Out Of The Box) solution:

> Found here: https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/

In Share Point Designer 2013, open the SP site that contains the list. Go to **Site Pages**
Create .aspx page. Then right-click on the new Site Page -> **Edit in Advanced View**

Without clicking anywhere in the code, straight in the **Insert** ribbon click **Data View**, and chose the wanted List.

Again without clicking in the code, a new ribbon should appear **List View Tool**, there under the **Web Part** tab in the section **Save Web Part** click on **To Site Gallery**.

Boom! Done! Now you should be able to add this custom web part anywhere in the Site Collection. And any change in the source list is shown straight away.

Notes: Search doesn't seem to appear in the web part. Spreadsheet view is not supported, though other regular views can be chosen from web part settings.

Hope this can help other SharePoint illiterates like me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of making connections between lists in the same site collection.  A Lookup column will grab data from another List and 'import' it, it's probably worth experimenting with, although it will not provide the 2 way connection you need.

The more likely option would be to use workflows - quite a steep learning curve with these though.  I can't quite recall whether workflows will update a list item in a different site collection, you'll have to check that.  In any case, you'd need to configure a workflow in such a way that Sharepoint is able to match an item A from List A with the corresponding item in List B; presumably you wish to link/connect items between lists.

There is also a 3rd party Sparqube lookup column which allows you to make connections between Lists in different site collections.  The gist of it is you use them to make the same ID / reference # appear in both list, then the make a connection this way.

Note - I do not work for Sparqube, just a user of it!

Comment: Yeah - I already have experience with SQL (and I would just use BCS, but sysadmin not happy with that), so I give everything a unique ID and use it to filter list webparts, that might not contain the name of a person or object.
Cause I do find the Webpart thing pretty useful until you hit the edge of the website. which I don't understand is, what is even the benefit of a site collection if things within it can't communicate OOTB...
Thank you for your answer though. I'll wait to see if anything comes closer to an answer, if not I'll mark yours! Cheers